# android different themes on landscape and portrait

Tags: android, android-theme, android-tabs

I have an activity that includes tabs. Everything looks good in portrait, but when in landscape the tabs are in the action bar by default and I really like this functionality. The problem is my action bar is green, my tabs are black and the tab selected color is also green. So when switched to landscape I have a green action bar and green tab selected, so there is no visual reference to which tab is selected.

I have tried using the approach having different values folders as in "values-port" and "values-land" and changing the tab selector drawable to black in the "values-land" folder, but the theme disappeared from the landscape and fell back to the default light with dark action bar.

I have done some research on this and found nothing based on two themes based on orientation, I found different themes based on version in which you have different values folders with the version number which is why I thought my approach would work. The developers site has nothing on incorporating two themes based on orientation, I dont even know if it's possible, I just assumed it was.

Comment: You can set the theme in code if you wish. You can do by checking the orientation in the onCreate() of the activity by checking `Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` and then calling `setTheme()` depending on the return values before you set the content view.

Comment: Yes, I was messing with that idea, but it only allows me to run once at runtime. What if the user changes orientation while on the screen, I can't get that approach to work for me and change themes while the user changes orientation while on the screen. I have 'android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"' on because I have custom drop down menu's that need to stay open if orientation changes. I'm assuming that's where a runnable would come in handy?, but I'm still new to java and have no idea how to implement those.

Comment: AFAIK, every time you change the orientation, your activity gets destroyed and recreated again which means this code won't only run once at runtime. It runs every time your activity is (re)created which is when you navigate away, when you change orientation, when you start it from an intent, etc.